# changing the values at indexes of array c#

Tags: c#

I have a string array of 8 elements, for example AB CD EF GH. And I would like do make the following order:

BA DC FE HG

The main idea is to change the value at index:
 1 with 0, 0 with 1
 ,3 with 2, 2 with 3
 ,5 with 4, 4 with 5
 ,7 with 6, 6 with 7

..... for any given length or content of the array.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can do that using a `for` loop. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just access the array by using `xor 1` on the index, that way you don't have to move anything or create a new array:

```
int n = arr[index ^ 1];
```

If you want to create a new array, you can just copy the array and access it that way from the source:

```
int[] newArr = new int[arr.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
  newArr[i] = arr[i ^ 1];
}
```

Note: this assumes that there are an even number of items in the array. If there would be an odd number of items, there is nothing to swap the last item with.